# Android: getting the TextView value next to the EditText element

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` whose contents are dynamically generated based on a dropdown option.
The `ListView` layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/unit_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="0.00"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight = "1" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I am about to add an `addTextChangeListener` to the `EditText` elements. The trouble is, I would like to know the value of the `TextView` that is above the selected `EditText` element. Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything in the API that would let me look an element above the currently selected element or anything like that and technically all of the id's for the `TextView` elements are the same. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they both have the same parent, so you could get the parent of the EditText, then grab the textview child ( parent.getChildAt(0), as it looks to be the first child).